# Bind text field to a value that is fetched from a REST Api using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, iphone, xamarin

I've started a Xamarin project using the template that is available in Visual Studio.
I wrote some services that fetches data from REST api. I have printed these values to the console and I am able to see that the services work like they should.

However I have troubles displaying the name of a user that I fetched from the Api.
I'm trying to do this in a ViewModel class.

```
using MyApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyApp.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
  {
   public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
    static readonly UserService CurrentUser = new UserService();

    public AboutViewModel()
    {
        //GetData().Wait();
        Title = "My App";
        OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("https://aka.ms/xamain-quickstart"));
        IsConnected = false;
        GetData();
    }

    protected async void GetData()
    {
        user = await CurrentUser.GetUser();
        Name = user.fullName;
    }

    public ICommand OpenWebCommand { get; }
    public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is the line from the .xaml file where it would be displayed:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title"/>
```

I know this is bad practice but I tried to hack it into working. It still doesn't work, and it displays nothing. It's the only thing I've managed so far that doesn't crash or make the app freeze. How bind to the variable "Name", when "Name" will eventually be set from an async void or task?

Comment: 1) are you setting the BindingContext for your page to the VM?  2) if you are loading your data *after* the page has loaded, your VM needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BaseViewModel` should probably implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or inherit from a class that already implements it, if you are using a MVVM framwork of sorts.

This could look something like:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, newValue))
        {
            return false;
        }

        backingField = newValue;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then for your properties in your ViewModel you could use `SetProperty` to ensure `PropertyChanged` is fired when their values change. This is needed for the UI they are bound to, to figure out that something changed.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
}
```

If you don't want to use `SetProperty` simply use `RaisePropertyChanged`:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at how the other variables were declared in BaseViewModel with some extra stuff. So basically like you did here. Now it works. Thanks!